# About Stream and getchar() and fgetc()

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch1, ch2;

    ch1 = fgetc(stdin);
    ch2 = getchar();

    fputc(ch1, stdout);
    putchar(ch2);

    return 0;
}
```

today I first learn about stream. I understood what stream is. But I can`t understood print result of this program. 
I pressed 'p' and enter key. And this program printed

**p** 
p 
Press any key to continue...

In book which i read, It said "enter key is a kind of ascii code, so you can see this result." But in front page, it said getchar and fgetc is a function that receive a character. But why it doesn`t print like

**a b** 
a
b

when i press 'a', space bar and 'b'?

May i know about stream and this two functions( getchar() and fgetc() )?

Comment: In the second example, `getchar()` will receive the *next character* from the stream, which will be a *space*!

Comment: You can simply search the internet about what these functions do. Is it easier to post a question here?

Comment: My question is "Doesn`t the stream get only one character?"

Comment: Your question should be, "Do these *functions* get only one character?", and that is best answered by their documentation. [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) and [`fgetc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)

Comment: The characters you hit on your keyboard are not given to your program until you hit the Enter key, and hitting that Enter key will also produce a newline on your terminal (At least normally that is the case, this depends on how you run your program)

Answer (score 1):

These three calls are, by definition, identical:

```
getchar()
getc(stdin)
fgetc(stdin)
```

So the program you posted is exactly equivalent to

```
ch1 = getchar();
ch2 = getchar();

putchar(ch1);
putchar(ch2);
```

If you're puzzled about how this program works, it's not because of any difference between `getchar`/`fgetc` or `putchar`/`putc`.

If you run this program and then press **p** and the enter key, I would expect `ch1` to end up containing `'p'`, and `ch2` to end up containing the newline character.  If you run this program and type "a b" and press the enter key, I would expect `ch1` to end up containing `'a'`, and `ch2` to end up containing the space character.  I would not expect this program to be able to print "`a b`", because it can only read and print two characters.

It's always tricky to think about character-by-character reading at first.  This is because, behind the scenes, the system is typically reading a whole *line* of text as you type, and then making the characters available to your program only after you press the Enter key.

It's easier to see what's going on if you print out a bit more information.  For example, here is a modification of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch1, ch2;

    ch1 = fgetc(stdin);
    ch2 = getchar();

    fprintf(stdout, "ch1 = '%c'\n", ch1);
    printf("ch2 = '%c'\n", ch2);
}
```

When I run this program and hit **p** and the Enter key, I see

```
ch1 = 'p'
ch2 = '
'
```

As you can see, `ch2` ended up containing the newline character.

When I run this program and hit **a** and a space and **b** and the Enter key, I see

```
ch1 = 'a'
ch2 = ' '
```

Well, more precisely, what I see is

```
a b
ch1 = 'a'
ch2 = ' '
```

But that first line `a b` is just where my computer echoed the characters as I typed them.  (See also [this web page](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6b.html), and especially the paragraph beginning "Finally, don't be disappointed".)

Again, there's no important difference between `fgetc(stdin)` and `getchar` here.  I could have written

```
ch1 = getchar();
ch2 = getchar();

printf("ch1 = '%c'\n", ch1);
printf("ch2 = '%c'\n", ch2);
```

and it would have done just the same thing.

Finally, it will probably help you see things more clearly if you write a program that reads and prints a whole *line* of characters.  Your first program read exactly two characters.  Here's a program that keeps reading and printing until it sees the `'\n'` character that marks the end of the line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while(c != '\n') {
        printf("c = '%c'\n", c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

This program reads one character.  If it's not the newline character `\n`, it prints it and reads another character.  If that's not the newline character, it prints it and reads another character.  It keeps reading and printing until it sees a newline character, then stops.  If I run this and type "a b c", I see

```
c = 'a'
c = ' '
c = 'b'
c = ' '
c = 'c'
```

(I don't see a line printed for the newline character, because this program stops reading immediately after it reads the newline character, and before it prints it.)

Again, what I actually see on my screen is

```
a b c
c = 'a'
c = ' '
c = 'b'
c = ' '
c = 'c'
```

but that first line `a b c` is just me typing the characters, before the program has a chance to read and print any of them.

Even for a simple test like this, I would never write the program quite that way, though.  I would write the loop as

```
while(c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    ...
```

because I would also want to make sure that the program stopped reading if it saw an end-of-file condition, that is, if `getchar` returned the special code `EOF`.